# How do I load a package from a package in a Lerna monorepo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, lerna, monorepo

I have:

```
packages
 -models
   -package.json
   -....
 -server
   -src
     -index.ts
   -package.json
```

In my `packages/server/package.json`, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@myapp/models": "../models",
```

In my `packages/server/src/index.ts`, I have:

```
import { sequelize } from '@myapp/models'
```

In my `packages/models/src/index.ts`, I have:

```
export type UserAttributes = userAttr


export { sequelize } from './sequelize';
```

but it gives me an error:

```
  Try `npm install @types/myapp__models` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@myapp/models';`

 import { sequelize } from '@myapp/models'
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lerna will take care of the dependencies between your local packages, you just need to make sure you set them up correctly. The first thing I would suggest is to go to `@myapp/models` and make sure that your `package.json` contains the fields you will need: `main` and more importantly `types` (or `typings` if you prefer):

```js
// packages/models/package.json

{
  // ...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  // ...
}
```

As you can see I made both of them point to some `dist` folder, which takes me to my second point - you will need to build every package as if it was a separate NPM module outside of the monorepo. I am not saying you need the `dist` folder, where you build it is up to you, you just need to make sure that from the outside your `@myapp/models` exposes `main` and `types` and that these are valid and existing `.js` and `.d.ts` files.

Now for the last piece of the puzzle - you need to declare your `@myapp/models` dependency as if it was a "real" package - you need to specify its version rather than point to a folder:

```js
// packages/server/package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "@myapp/models": "0.0.1" // Put the actual version from packages/models/package.json here
    // ...
  }
}
```

Lerna will notice that this is a local package and will install & link it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanation. I finally found this after days of searching :) Especially the main and types part.

Comment: Good answer, I'd just like to add that you don't need to specify the actual `@myapp/models` version, just put `workspace:*` and lerna/yarn will figure out the correct version for you, otherwise it'll be very difficult to keep this up-to-date as your application grows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Lerna, but a good tool to deal with monorepos is [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

1. cd packages/models
2. npm link
3. cd packages/server
4. restore the version in dependencies `"@myapp/models": "x.y.z",`
5. npm link @myapp/models

It should be enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

lerna bootstrap first then yarn add <package_name> works
Or
lerna bootstrap first, then add the package and the target version then run yarn.

Answer (score 0):

After you put in the dependencies in your server's package.json, you just need to run

```
lerna run --stream build
```

And your local should be able to access to it.